# Using an IOC container as dependency resolver for MVC5 throws ' cannot create an instance of an interface ' error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject

I am trying to simply use an IOC container ( ninject at present ) as the dependency resolver for MVC5.
This used to work fine in MVC4, visual studio 2012, but now with VS2013 and MVC5 , I just can't get the resolver to inject a dependency in my controller.This isn't specific to ninject, I have tried SimpleInjector and Unity too - same error

I just want to be able to inject this class in my home controller.

```
    public interface ITest
    {
        void dummyMethod();
    }


     public class Test : ITest
    {
            public void dummyMethod()
            {
            };
    }
```

This is the dependency resolver

```
 public class NinjectDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
    {
        private IKernel kernel;
        public NinjectDependencyResolver()
        {
            kernel = new StandardKernel();
            AddBindings();
        }
        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
        return kernel.TryGet(serviceType);
        }


            public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
            {
                 return kernel.GetAll(serviceType);
            }
            private void AddBindings()
            {
                kernel.Bind<ITest>().To<Test>();

            }
    }
```

This is the global.asax.cs

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver());
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
```

and this is my HomeController

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(ITest test)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

but when I run this I keep getting

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Cannot create an instance of an interface.
```

I have also tried creating a brand new project ( MVC 5) - same error

I have tried MVC5, and then also upgrading to 5.2.2. Same error

Any help greatly appreciated. I think that the resolver is never being called for some reason, even though if I put a breakpoint at

```
  kernel.Bind<ITest>().To<Test>();
```

it does stop there.... No idea what is happening :(

Comment: You cannot inject paramters to an action. You need to inject your dependencies in your constroller's constructor : `public class HomeController : Controller
{
private ITest;
public HomeController(ITest test) { this.test = test: }
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
      //you test here
        return View();
    }
}`

Comment: OH MY SCENTED TROUSERS!!!! I cannot believe I missed that.... May the spirit of Bill Gates bless you sir !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you cannot inject parameters into your action methods.

You need to inject your dependencies in your constroller's constructor :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ITest test;

    public HomeController(ITest test)
    {
        this.test = this;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //use test here
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "normally" mean? I'm learning about dependency injection and I read that there can be constructor injection and setter injection.

Comment: @starsplusplus the "normally" was about the ASP.NET MVC part because there you could implement a custom `IActionInvoker` where you can implement also injection of action parameters. But of course the default implementation does not support it. So you are right most of the dependency injection containers only supporting constructor and setter injection.

Comment: Can I use dependency Injection somewhere else than controllers, e.g. my own class' constructor? I'll be grateful if you could help me with [this problem](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/291522/184905).